# Associated ECT only displays ID (not title) in external list

Tags: external-content-type, external-list

I have created two ECTs, let's call them country and city for clarity.  I have also created an association with city as the child and country as the parent.  When I create an external list for city, it appears roughly as follows:

```
City                    Country
================        =================
London                  1
Manchester              1
New York                2
Los Angeles             2
Tokyo                   3
```

When I actually go in and edit an item, I get an ECT picker which allows me to pick using the friendly names (Great Britain, USA, etc.) thanks to the city-> country association. However, I would like the external list to also display the friendly name rather than the country ID, which is just a database autoincrement and not useful at all for the end user.

Note: I'm creating a SQL server ECT, with all operations being implemented with stored procs

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as follows:

In my Read Item stored procedure for the City ECT, I returned City, Country (the ID) and Country Description.  In my Read List stored procedure for the City ECT, I returned only City and Country Description, so that the Read List displayed as:

```
City                    Country Description
================        ===================
London                  United Kingdom
Manchester              United Kingdom
New York                United States
Los Angeles             United States
Tokyo                   Japan
```

My experience is that the Read Item method must define all fields used in Read List, but the opposite is not true: Read List does not need to contain all of the fields that exist in Read Item.

Comment: Note: if you have caching enabled, this could create an issue, because the "calculated fields" - in this case, country description - will not be updated properly.